# I need to join two commands

Tags: windows-7

Using the command prompt I would like to create a folder named "2013 Vacation Florida" (without quotes), Inside this folder I want to create sequentially dated folders, one for each day. These folders would be numbered "2013-04-01 to 2013-04-30" without quotes (2013 April 1st day etc). I can make the first folder by using the command

```
            mkdir "2013 Vacation Florida"
```

I can create all the daily folders by using the command

```
              for /l %a in (1,1,30) do md "2013-04-%a"
```

Question- How  would I join these two commands into one?

I am using windows 7.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9):

`mkdir` automatically creates all parent directories, so you can use this:

```
for /l %a in (1,1,30) do md "2013 Vacation Florida\2013-04-%a"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, only three minutes. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @bphurl to mark an answer as having solved your problem, please click the check mark to the left of the answer.